# Variant of rgeos::gUnion that won't dissolve adjacent polygons?

Tags: r, gis, geos, r-sp

I have some clusters of adjacent parcels that I would like to combine, but I want the parcel boundaries within each cluster to be preserved. If I use something like `Reduce(geom_list, gUnion)` then adjacent boundaries are dissolved.

Here is a simple and reproducible example of what I would like, more or less implemented in pure R: https://gist.github.com/holstius/37c0ff01109e28ff817a. I would be surprised if `GEOS` doesn't already implement this natively, but I couldn't identify an `rgeos` binding that would do what I want.

Is there a variant of `rgeos::gUnion` that *won't* dissolve adjacent polygons?

---

(**edit**: sketchy code example with `%>%` removed in favor of https://gist.github.com/holstius/37c0ff01109e28ff817a)

Comment: It is not clear to me what you mean with "combine" but without wanting to dissolve. Because I am not familiar with the `.` and `%>%` syntax, your example sketch doesn't help me, and a reproducible example is missing.

Comment: Thanks for weighing in. Please give me a few minutes to cook up a reproducible example using just base R and `sp` and/or `maptools`. Hopefully that will clarify the intent.

Comment: @edzer-pebesma Please see https://gist.github.com/holstius/37c0ff01109e28ff817a for a simple and reproducible example. I suppose the logic of making the `ID`s of all the `Polygons` unique could be implemented as in `sp::rbind.SpatialPolygons(..., makeUniqueIDs = TRUE)`. But the idea is just to show that the geometries are merged without dissolving adjacent boundaries.

Comment: I still don't see how your `merge` improves over sp's `rbind`; I also don't see why you'd call it `merge`, given `base::merge` and its counterpart in sp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `raster::aggregate( , dissolve=FALSE)` for that. It will combine geometries, but not dissolve boundaries.